# Display user name with flags

Tags: users, flags

I've this code who show the number of users who 'flagged me' (I'm using flag module)

```
$flag = flag_get_flag('poke');

if ($flag) {
  print "The number of people who voted for this proposal:";
  print $flag->get_count($user->uid);
}
```

I want to show a list of the user name instead.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Where do you want to display these usernames? Is the Flag you're talking about a user Flag? Maybe you're looking for the Views module? You can easily create a View that displays all the users who flagged a certain user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the particular flag api to get the usernames of flagged node.
But it can be possible using custom implementation. Here is code

```
function get_usernames_flagged_node($entity_id, $flag_name) { //Supply node_id and flag_name
  $get_all_nodes_of_flagged = flag_get_flag_flagging_data($flag_name);
  $flagged_content_detail = array();
  $username = array();
  foreach($get_all_nodes_of_flagged as $get_all_nodes_of_flags) {
    $flagged_content_detail[] = $get_all_nodes_of_flags;
  }
  foreach($flagged_content_detail as $flag_content) {
    if($entity_id == $flag_content->entity_id) {
     $user=user_load($flag_content->uid);
     $username[]=$user->name;
    }
  }
  return $username;
}
```

It can be also possible using views and flag modules. For your reference see this [page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166872/displaying-content-flagged-by-user-name-with-flag-module)